# Using SAS token to upload Blob content

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I'm having difficulty in using a Blob SAS token to write a file to a Blob in Azure via Powershell.

The code I'm using to generate the SAS token is:

```
$storageContext = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageName

$token = New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken -Container $conName -Context $storageContext.Context -Blob $blobName -ExpiryTime $expiry -Permission rw -FullUri
```

This generates a token as expected: `https://name.blob.core.windows.net/container/test.json?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=abc123&se=2017-03-07T12%3A58%3A52Z&sp=rw`

If I use this in the browser it's working fine and downloading the file as expected. However, I can't use this to upload a file. Whenever I try I'm receiving a (403) Forbidden. The code I'm using to upload is:

```
$accountContext = New-AzureStorageContext -SasToken $sasToken

Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $accountContext.Context | Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $blobFile
```

I've successfully been using a method similar to this to set Blob content after making a call to `Add-AzureRmAccount` to authenticate.

I've also tried to use a Container SAS token but I keep getting a 403 error with that.

The fact that the token works for a read leads me to believe that I'm missing something in my Powershell script  - can anyone shed any light on what that is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The fact that the token works for a read leads me to believe that I'm
>   missing something in my Powershell script - can anyone shed any light
>   on what that is?

I believe the problem is with the following line of code:

```
Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $accountContext.Context
```

Two things here:

1. This cmdlet tries to list the blob containers in your storage account. In order to list blob containers using SAS, you would need an `Account SAS` where as the SAS you're using is a `Container SAS`.
2. Your SAS only has `Read` and `Write` permission. For listing containers, you would need `List` permission as well.

I would recommend simply using `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` Cmdlet and provide necessary information to it instead of getting the container name through pipeline.

```
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $blobFile -Container $conName -Context $accountContext.Context -Blob $blobName
```

Comment: I've confirmed that the call to `Get-AzureStorageContainer` is throwing a 403 when creating a `Blob SAS`. I changed my code to create a `Container SAS` with rwl and call `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` directly but still getting a 403.

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest code you're using? Thanks.

Comment: I've resolved the issue. What you have said is working, I was using the `-FullUri` flag when creating a SAS token. Removing this flag gave me the query string part of the token only which is now allowing me to upload the blob. Thanks.