# Using Only a SAS Token To Upload in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, azure-sas

I have a [SAS Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) in the form:

`https://name.blob.core.windows.net/container?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=abc123&se=2017-03-07T12%3A58%3A52Z&sp=rw`

I am attempting to use an `Az` Provided Cmdlet in Powershell to upload content to this blob. I am unable to find an API that simply takes the above SAS token and a file to upload.

Reading this [reddit post](https://old.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/fgmu9o/outside_of_azcopy_has_anyone_written_any_scripts/) it seems like my options are:

1. Parse out the `StorageAccountName` (in the example `name`), `Container` (in the example `container`) and `SASToken` (in the example above `sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=abc123&se=2017-03-07T12%3A58%3A52Z&sp=rw`) and then use `New-AzStorageContext`/`Set-AzStorageBlobContent`. This more or less is the answer in this StackOverflow Post ([Connect to Azure Storage Account using only SAS token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428001/connect-to-azure-storage-account-using-only-sas-token))
2. Use `Invoke-WebRequest` or its kin to basically perform the REST call myself.

I would like to use as many `Az` provided cmdlets possible so starting with option 1, there doesn't seem to be an API to parse this, the closest I can find is this StackOverflow Post ([Using SAS token to upload Blob content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646997/using-sas-token-to-upload-blob-content)) talking about using [CloudBlockBlob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob?view=azure-dotnet-legacy), however it is unclear if this class is available to me in PowerShell.

To these ends I've created a Regex that appears to work, but is most likely brittle, is there a better way to do this?

```
$SASUri = https://name.blob.core.windows.net/container?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=abc123&se=2017-03-07T12%3A58%3A52Z&sp=rw
$fileToUpload = 'Test.json'

$regex = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($SASUri, '(?i)\/+(?<StorageAccountName>.*?)\..*\/(?<Container>.*)\?(?<SASToken>.*)')
$storageAccountName = $regex.Groups['StorageAccountName'].Value
$container = $regex.Groups['Container'].Value
$sasToken = $regex.Groups['SASToken'].Value

$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -SasToken $sasToken
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File $fileToUpload -Container $container -Context $storageContext -Force
```

### To Restate The Questions

1. Is there an `Az` Cmdlet that takes the SAS URI and SAS Token to allow upload?
2. (If not) Is there an API to parse the SAS URI + SAS Token?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering `$SASUri` is a URI, you can get a `System.Uri` object using something like:

```
$uri = [System.Uri] $SASUri
```

Once you have that, you can get the container name and the SAS token using something like:

```
$storageAccountName = $uri.DnsSafeHost.Split(".")[0]
$container = $uri.LocalPath.Substring(1)
$sasToken = $uri.Query
```

After that your code should work just fine:

```
$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -SasToken $sasToken
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File $fileToUpload -Container $container -Context $storageContext -Force
```

Comment: Thank you! one minor nit it appears that you'll need to remove the `?` from the $sasToken   but otherwise looks solid!